# Plot summary of unique observations with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to count unique observations via a ggplot formula?  For instance by somehow achieving the same result as this by cutting the middle line?  My efforts so far e.g. using geom_histogram with stat='bin' have failed.

```
set.seed(1)
d = data.frame(year = sample(2005:2009, 50, prob = 1:5, rep=T), 
               group = sample(letters, 50, prob = 1:26, rep=T))
d2 = plyr::count(unique(d)$year)
ggplot(d2, aes(x, freq)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + labs(x='year', y='count of groups')
```

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(d, aes(year, group)) + geom_bar(stat='bin')` fails with `Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin"` etc..  Have also tried `aes(year:group)` in case an interaction was required - failed with `arguments imply differing number of rows`..  What formula do you mean?

Comment: `ggplot(unique(d), aes(x = as.factor(year))) + stat_bin() + labs(x='year', y='count of groups')` will do.

Comment: That's a better method thanks @lukeA, want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_bin()` will do the trick like this:

```
ggplot(unique(d), aes(x = as.factor(year))) + 
  stat_bin() + 
  labs(x='year', y='count of groups')
```